# Update gridview content on textbox_TextChanged event outside the gridview

Tags: c#, gridview

I have searched for this but could not find any solution for `textchanged` event outside the gridview causing changes in results. I am unable to attach image being a newbie. I want results shown in gridview through data table to update according to what I type in textbox placed outside of gridview. code in c# will be appreciated. In the end, I want to retrieve ID on pressing ENTER key to use further.

```
    private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DataTable table = new DataTable();
            string sql; table.Columns.Add("Name");


            dbconnect db = new dbconnect();
            db.createconnection();
            sql = "select custcompany from customer";
            db.dbadapter = new OleDbDataAdapter(sql, db.dbconnection);
            DataTable dtt = new DataTable();
            db.dbadapter.Fill(dtt);

            for (int i = 0; i < dtt.Rows.Count; i++)
            {
                table.Rows.Add(dtt.Rows[i][0]);
            }

            sql = "select suppcompany from supplier";
            db.dbadapter = new OleDbDataAdapter(sql, db.dbconnection);
            DataTable dtt1 = new DataTable();
            db.dbadapter.Fill(dtt1);

            for (int i = 0; i < dtt1.Rows.Count; i++)
            {
                table.Rows.Add(dtt1.Rows[i][0]);
            }
            dataGridView1.DataSource = table;


            if (textBox1.Text != "")
            {

                DataView dv = new DataView();
                dv.RowFilter = string.Format("Name = '{0}'", textBox1.Text);
                dataGridView1.DataSource = dv;


            }
            else if (textBox1.Text == "")
            {
                dataGridView1.DataSource = table;
            }
        }
```

`table` is the name of DataTable populated on Load event.

Comment: What you have tried before?

Comment: You are in right direction. Just `Databind` the gridview after declaring the `DataSource`. But must focus out of the textbox to see the change.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If test box has value, you are creating a new instance of `DataView` and assigning it to the `dataGridView1`, my question is **is there value in DataView object?** If you are doing exactly what you have given in the question then it won't work, because `dv` doesn't have value to show in the `dataGridView1`.

Get the `table` data on `TextChanged` event by accessing the database. If you have any code where you are getting the database values into the `table` then use it in this event before binding to the `DataGridView1`.

Because the `table` value will be lost after `PostBack`. So you need to reload the value into `table` again. Try the following,

```
private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //table = fill the table with proper values by accessing the database
    if (textBox1.Text != "")
    {
        DataView dv = table.DefaultView;
        dv.RowFilter = string.Format("Name = '{0}'", textBox1.Text);
        dataGridView1.DataSource = dv;
        dataGridView1.DataBind();
    }
    else if (textBox1.Text == "")
    {
        dataGridView1.DataSource = table;
        dataGridView1.DataBind();
    }
}
```

**Update**

To search names that begins with letters use,

```
dv.RowFilter = string.Format("Name like  '{0}%'", textBox1.Text);
```

To search names that contains a letters use,

```
dv.RowFilter = string.Format("Name like  '%{0}%'", textBox1.Text);
```

To search names that ends with letters,

```
dv.RowFilter = string.Format("Name like  '%{0}'", textBox1.Text);
```

Comment: I am now getting results in gridview but it only shows results when it matches complete name in available in table. How can I show names of person even if they match a "letter"? like if I write "john", it populate grid but I want "john" to appear even when I press "j".

Comment: @user3510905 First assignment (`dataGridView1.DataSource = table;`) outside the `if-else` block is not necessary, then you need to add `dataGridView1.DataBind();` whenever you are assigning a `DataSource`. Instead of `DataView dv = new DataView();` add `DataView dv = table.DefaultView;`.

Comment: @user3510905 **Or** After the end of `for` block, use the `if-else` block what I have added in my answer.

Comment: I did the same and  it worked. kindly look at my edited comment just under your answer for my new problem.

Comment: @user3510905 I have updated the answer, unable to format properly because of mobile keyboard.

Comment: Ofcourse there is "like". I am just out of practice and need to recall many things. Thanks for help :)